# Proving that two summations are equivalent: $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\sum_{i=1}^n i)^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

Give a constructive proof to show that for all $n \geq 1$ ,

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i)^2$

Observe that $(n+1)^4 - n^4 = 4n^3 + 6n^2 + 4n + 1$ .

---

Now, the two following equalities are obvious:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + ... + n^3$

$(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i)^2 = (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)^2$

And they are both obviously equivalent given the first few test cases:

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = A(n)$

- $A(1) = 1^3 = 1$
- $A(2) = 1^3 + 2^3 = 1 + 8 = 9$
- $A(3) = 1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 = 9 + 27 = 36$

$(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i)^2 = B(n)$

- $B(1) = (1)^2 = 1$
- $B(2) = (1 + 2)^2 =9 $
- $B(3) = (1 + 2 + 3)^2 = 36$

Now, I am thinking of finding the closed-forms for both functions in the hopes that they are indeed the same. Then I would prove those closed forms to work by induction. But:

1. I don't know if that would be a sound way to do it.
2. I don't know if this would even qualify as constructive, as the question requests.

As you may tell, I am no math major. I am a Computer Science major, though. This is a computing fundamentals class. I took discrete 1.5 years ago, so my knowledge is about as fresh as a litter box. I've been in quite a rut for a few hours over this.

Comment: Did you try induction? You've already established a base case

Comment: ^very helpful comment, it made me understand induction a lot.

Comment: What is a *constructive proof*?

Comment: "Proof by construction" may ring a louder bell.

Comment: You do not want to prove those two expresions are equivalent: you want to prove they are equal.

Comment: @induktio Forgive me, I am slow to comprehend math. But I see that your answer is meticulously spelled out. Thx!

Comment: @Chuckles You're welcome! I hope it helps out--I tried to make each step clear. Hopefully it answers your question. Note that $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^n i.$$ I assume you can use this well-known fact. If not, you can prove that by induction as well (many proofs of it are available online and I would imagine some are even on here at MSE).

Comment: Classic me: I remember the name Gauss, but I don't remember his famous equation. Is the Imitation Game by itself really worth much, then? LOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your goal is to prove the statement $S(n)$ for all $n\geq 1$ where
$$
S(n) : 1^3 + 2^3 +3^3 +\cdots + n^3 = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2.
$$
Using $\Sigma$-notation, we may rewrite $S(n)$ as follows:
$$
S(n) : \sum_{r=1}^n r^3 = \left[\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]^2.
$$
**Base step:** The statement $S(1)$ says that $(1)^3 = (1)^2$ which is true because $1=1$.

**Inductive step [$S(k)\to S(k+1)$]:** Fix some $k\geq 1$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume that
$$
S(k) : \sum_{r=1}^k r^3 = \left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2
$$
holds. To be proved is that
$$
S(k+1) : \sum_{r=1}^{k+1} r^3 = \left[\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}{2}\right]^2
$$
follows. Beginning with the left side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{k+1}r^3 &= \sum_{r=1}^k r^3 + (k+1)^3\tag{evaluate sum for $i=k+1$}\\[1em]
                    &= \left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2+(k+1)^3\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[1em]
                    &= \frac{(k+1)^2}{4}[k^2+4(k+1)]\tag{factor out $\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}$}\\[1em]
                    &= \frac{(k+1)^2}{4}[(k+2)(k+2)]\tag{factor quadratic}\\[1em]
                    &= \frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}\tag{multiply and rearrange}\\[1em]
                    &= \left[\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\right]^2\tag{rearrange}\\[1em]
                    &= \left[\frac{(k+1)((k+1)+1)}{2}\right]^2,\tag{rearrange}
\end{align}
one arrives at the right side of $S(k+1)$, thereby showing that $S(k+1)$ is also true, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, it is proved that for all $n\geq 1$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, that the statement $S(n)$ is true.

**Note:** The step where $\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{4}$ is factored out is an important one. If we do not factor this out and, instead, choose to expand $(k+1)^3$, the problem becomes much more messy than it needs to be.

Comment: This is meticulous and great. I see the proof. Now I'm just getting stuck with the algebra where you factor out $\dfrac{(k+1)^2}{4}$ , but that is minimal. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: This is what is currently on paper in front of me: $\dfrac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} + (k+1)(k+1)(k+1)$ . I'm an idiot.

Comment: I'm putting in the towel tonight. I'll give this a try tomorrow. I simply don't have another hour. I wish I could understand this as rapidly as you all seem to.

Comment: \begin{align}\left[\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\right]^2+(k+1)^3 &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)(k+1)^2\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{k^2(k+1)^2+4k(k+1)^2+4(k+1)^2}{4}\\ &\Longleftrightarrow \frac{(k+1)^2}{4}[k^2+4(k+1)] \end{align}

Answer (score 3):

We prove $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i)^2$.

$i = 1$ means $1^3 = 1^2$.

Assume true for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$. We prove it's true for $i = n+1$.

Well, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} i^3 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3 + (n+1)^3 = (\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i)^2 + (n+1)^3$.

Now, using the fact that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$, can you finish the proof?

Comment: I think you forgot some cubeds.

Comment: Thanks I've edited my answer now.

Comment: Okay, this answer helps me to understand how this is "constructive." Forgive the math gears in my head, for they're dusty and poorly lubricated. I'll try to finish it out.

Comment: @Chuckles the rest is algebra. Just use manipulation of expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I proposed here another way to approach: consider the identity
$$ n^4=\sum_{i=1}^n {r^4-(r-1)^4}=\sum_{i=1}^n 4i^3-6i^2+4i-1.$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{n^4+1}{4}+\frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2-\sum_{i=1}^n i. $$
Simpify the expression and you get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\binom{n+1}{2}^2. $$

This method allows one recursively to find explicitely, given a positive integer $k$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but as a beginner, I fail to understand this. It did bring me a little closer to understanding my professor's hint at the bottom of the question, but for me it's only correlative and I can't really comprehend it. Thanks though!

Comment: Except the idea of telescopic sum at the first line, there is nothing except algebraic manipulations :) Good luck with your studies

Comment: I'm that bad. For instance, from your nice, clean, short answer, the following questions popped up: (1) How is the professor's hint relevant to solving the problem? (2) On the line "Simplify the expression and you get...", I do not understand the notation to the right of the equals sign. (3) Algebra.  

It's not your fault! 'Tis my visual brain.

Comment: (1) The hint is used exactly like in this answer: the sum of difference of forth powers is simply $n^4$, and it can be expressed as sum of monomials with degree at most $3$: that's the trick; I mean, if you mean how to compute the sum $1+\ldots+n$, the sum $1^2+\ldots+n^2$,..., the sum $1^k+\ldots+n^k$, then you know also how to compute $1^{k+1}+\ldots+n^{k+1}$. This was the hint of your professor; when you become a little pedantic you will generalize this argument with Bernoulli's numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number

Comment: (2) Maybe I could be clearer; the meaning of $$\frac{n^4+1}{4}+\frac{3}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n i^2-\sum_{i=1}^n i$$ is exactly $$\frac{n^4}{4}+\frac{6}{4}(1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2)-\frac{4}{4}(1+2+\ldots+n)+\frac{1}{4}$$ (just writing explicitely the sums)

Comment: (3) It is enough to practice a bit :)

Comment: Thanks @Paolo! I think reviewing algebra will help me to see proofs a little better. I feel like a lot of proving things is rearranging them to look like other things. Thx for the explanations.