# Show that $1^3+2^3+3^3+\text{...}+n^3=(1+2+3+\text{...}+n)^2$

Tags: induction

Show that $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\text{...}+n^3=(1+2+3+\text{...}+n)^2$$ For $n=1$ we have $$1^3=1^2$$
which is obviously true. Assume that $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\text{...}+k^3=(1+2+3+\text{...}+k)^2$$is true for some positive integer $k\ge1$. We shall now prove that it is also true for $n=k+1$. I don't see how can we do that. $$1^3+2^3+3^3+\text{...}+k^3+(k+1)^3\overset{?}{=}(1+2+3+\text{...}+k+(k+1))^2$$
The LHS is $$(1+2+3+\text{...}+k)^2+(k+1)^3=...$$

Comment: Hint: it's a *lot* easier if you can assume (or show by induction) that $1 + 2 + \dots + k = \frac 12 k(k+1)$ first.

Comment: A more interesting question, IMHO is: find a geometric proof of this statement.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1125766/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1111443/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/996083/42969

Comment: For a visual proof, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3938027/42969.

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer and then deleted it, because my answer is a duplicate.

Comment: @EliasCosta, obviously I wasn't familiar with the fact that $1+2+\text{...}+k=\dfrac12k(k+1)$, so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + k^3 + (k+1)^3 = (1+2+ \dots + k+k+1)^2$.

It's a *lot* easier if you can assume (or show by induction) that $1 + 2 + \dots + k = \frac 12 k(k+1)$ first.

Using that result,

$1^3 + 2^3 + \dots + k^3 + (k+1)^3
\\= (\frac 12k(k+1))^2 + (k+1)^3
\\= (\frac12)^2(k+1)^2(k^2 + 4k +4)
\\= (\frac12)^2(k+1)^2(k+2)^2
\\= (1 + 2 + \dots + k+k+1)^2$

as required.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Can you clarify how $$(\frac12)^2(k+1)^2(k+2)^2)$$ is equal to the RHS?

Comment: See the duplicate for an induction proof. This question has been asked several times already.

Comment: @Medi That's equal to $(\frac 12(k+1)(k+2))^2 = (1 + 2 + \dots + k+1)^2$.  It's basically reversing the lemma I asked you to show first. Do you see?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, I get your point, and what you wrote is true. I did want to help the OP out as they wrote a good quality question and gave good details of their doubt.

Comment: @Deepak, I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @DietrichBurde, if you can't help me, I really don't see what's the point of you writing useless comments under people's tries to assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a beautiful visual proof. I got the picture from Google.
[image]

The blocks on the left are of course cubes and not squares as they may look like.

Comment: Have you seen [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938027/can-someone-explain-this-visual-proof-of-1-2-3-n2-13-23-3?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: @DietrichBurde no, I didn't see that. That one's nicer of course. But, that's no reason for the downvote- my answer is correct and I put my own effort in it.